# AngularJS forEach set object properties in ng-repeat found set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat displaying items from json, based on what the user enters into a field it can be filtered.

`<tr ng-repeat="i in filteredItems = (iso3166 | filter: {alpha_2: isoQuery})">`

this all works as expected.

Each item in the group ("iso3166") has 3 boolean values, "restricted", "unrestricted", and "unclassified", for each of the columns "license", "prohibited", and "size".

The user can set one of these values in each column in each row to true or false:

[image]

This works fine.

What I need to add is an "ALL" row at the top that will set every item in the filtered set to whichever button was clicked in each column.

[image]

In other words, if the user clicks the ALL rows "restricted" button in the "license" column, every row's "license" "restricted" value should be toggled to true or false.  I'm not sure of the syntax to set the value.

Now I have the ng-click as

`ng-click="setAll('col1','licensed')"`

and the function as

```
  $scope.setAll = function (column, value) {
    angular.forEach($scope.filteredItems, function (value, key) {
      ??
    });
  };
```

How do I assign the correct value to each row in the loop?

Comment: Sorry. Edited the question.

Comment: But if you have the filtered items, why not just do `value[column] = value`?

Comment: You need to change the name of the local variable though, otherwise it gets shadowed.. `function(item, key) { item[column] = value; }`

Comment: That was exactly my issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your inner function shadows the `value` variable. Rename the local variable to something else in order to change it.

```
$scope.setAll = function (column, value) {
  angular.forEach($scope.filteredItems, function (item, key) {
    item[column] = value;
  });
};
```